# M-Theory and computer simulation

Tags: string-theory, simulations, computer

I have a question. Is it possible to perform computer simulations based on the M-Theory?

I was looking for such simulators or source codes but I have not found anything.

However, M-theory must have a mathematical model that can be saved as a code to be executed by the computer.

Something like this might work? Leaving aside the problem of computational complexity.

Comment: Nope. I don't think M-theory is a well-defined model at this point.

Comment: I don't think every mathematical model has to be computable, but you should probably consult some set/category theorist or logician for that.

Comment: Witten has given an existence proof for such a theory (and mathematicians may even doubt that?), but I have not seen an actual formulation as a set of equations of motion. Additionally, one may ask, what would you do with numerical results from such a simulation? IMHO, so far not even numerical attempts at string theory have yielded experimentally useful predictions, albeit my knowledge about these things is kind of old.

Comment: Equations in advanced theoretical physics are often very hard to solve or approximately solve. The form of M-theory that is easiest to simulate might be the BFSS matrix model, but that's M-theory with 10 of the space dimensions large, rather than just 3.